# Google Apps Script to filter messages sent to mulple recipients and has attachement

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, spam

I get these spam emails from multiple accounts with only a few things in common.
The messages include me and several other recipients in the To field (4+)
They all have pdf attachments
Always sourced from a different gmail account. All recipients are also gmail accounts.

I've been hacking at some gmail code but really do not know what I'm doing.

I created a filter that labels all emails with pdf attachments as "pdf"

My pseudo logic:

For messages labeled pdf {
if number of recipients >= 4
mark it as spam
}

Comment: Instead of building a spam filter spend your time creating and email whitelist that includes the emails that you wish to received and don't except any of the others.    It's much easier to manage.

Comment: Whitelist wouldn't work for my needs but it's a valid point. This particular spam scenario has been an increasing issue for a while. Sourced by gmail accounts. Changing username. Weaponized pdfs. But multiple recipients. I have to believe there's a way to create this rule. I'll keep banging away. Thought maybe someone more better scripter would figure this out quickly.

Comment: Oh yeah there a way to create the rule you describe but the problem is that spam is a never ending battle and once I developed a tool to help me manage my white list spam became a non problem.